# BDD for Front-End Code?

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, bdd, jasmine

Currently I am working with the programmers and UX at my company to create a Pattern/Component Library for use in our software. Think of it as our own version of something like Twitter Bootstrap, jQuery UI, or Yahoo! Design pattern library.

I will be creating this library using HTML5, CSS3, and jQuery (possibly with CoffeeScript). Should I be using a library like Jasmine to be testing my js? The reason I ask is because any components that use jQuery won't really be doing much more than fancy effects. So, I guess, is it worth it to test things like, "Does this button change class on hover?" or "Does my accordion menu work correctly?"

I am unfamiliar with testing practices for simple front-end code, so I wanted some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say get the browser tests in there, you can use Jasmine or Selenium (I try to use Selenium as much as possible).

Besides the basic "does this work like it is supposed to" testing, when there is a major update to something like jQuery, you can quickly re-run your test suite and see what fails. This will save you a lot of time, and once you've fixed the issues (if any), you'll be ready for the next thing to come down the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, and I kind of figured Stack Overflow would tell me to do it just for code maintenance. But it didn't quite occur to me to think of updates and backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If there is logic in your javascript then unit testing makes sense. Keep a test suite for that.

Also, concentrate on System tests which test the end to end stuff . In your case browser testing with a tool like selenium is also important. This helps solve regression issues when libraries are updated especially for JS where library updates are frequent or sometimes libraries are swapped for one another.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways I've found to use BDD with libraries and frameworks is to create a few small applications which actually use the framework. These also then provide documentation to anyone else who needs to know how to use it. This is actually how most of the BDD frameworks themselves (JBehave, Cucumber, etc.) were designed. You can see an example of something similar [here](https://code.google.com/p/wipflash/), where I used a petshop to drive an automation tool, and wrote the scenarios around the petshop.

For the aesthetics, you're probably going to be testing them manually anyway, and @ashutosh-raina's suggestion of unit testing any logic here is great. When you write the scenarios for the toy apps, focus on [what they can do](https://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/Example.PetShop.Scenarios/PetRegistrationAndPurchase.cs) rather than how they do it, and you'll probably find you cover most of your functionality at a full-stack level. Don't worry about forcing it as the unit tests will do the rest. The examples I've linked to are .NET but should give you an idea of what I mean.

The other benefit of toy apps is that if you get a new request, you can usually find a way to add something or change the app to demonstrate that request, then add it easily and be sure that it works.

If you write too many scenarios, your suite will quickly become unmaintainable and make your code harder to change, which is the exact opposite of what you want.